# (Update Needed) shows when booting MacBook Pro 2011

Tags: macos, hard-drive, osx-mavericks

After erasing the hard drive of my MacBook Pro 2011, I realized that I must've done something wrong, because whenever I boot, the computer will ask for the hard drive password. Might this have to do with the fact that I chose Journaled, Encrypted?

Comment: Same problem after booting Windows, then using the bootcamp tools to select the macOS boot volume. Have to reboot into rescue mode and select the macOS volume from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this too. If you go to the "Security" preference pane, you should see a message that says "File Vault is turned on for the disk . Some users are not able to unlock the disk." Click the padlock in the lower left of the preference pane to authenticate, then click "Enable Users" and select which users you want to allow. They'll then be able to unlock the disk when logging in, instead of at boot time.

[image: Screen shot of corrective actions]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue after doing an erase/encrypt of the disk followed by a re-install of OS/X.  I just put in the password I used to encrypt the drive and it allowed me to log in and then continue the install.